# Subtract two ranges to add formula in a part of a column table

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add formula into one table column, except the first row of this same column (whose value need to be fixed).
So I've try to subtract the column data range from his first cell :

```
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
rng1 = Sheets("MySheet").ListObjects("MyTable").ListColumns("Column2").DataBodyRange
rng2 = Sheets("MySheet").ListObjects("MyTable").ListColumns("Column2").DataBodyRange.Cells(1)
rng3 = rng1 - rng2
rng3.Formula = "=SUM(D179;G179)"
```

But this return me an execution error '91'

Comment: You need to use **Set**

Answer (score 0):

As Gary's says, you need to set the range,
For example:

```
 Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
    set rng1 = Sheets("MySheet").ListObjects("MyTable").ListColumns("Column2").DataBodyRange
   set rng2 = Sheets("MySheet").ListObjects("MyTable").ListColumns("Column2").DataBodyRange.Cells(1)
    'rng3 = rng1 - rng2 'you have not indicate what rng3 range is
    rng3.Formula = "=SUM(D179;G179)"'still no indication what rng3 is
```